# Calcul of color in a triangle - searching the methode employed by opengl

Tags: opengl

I'm always trying to understand all the principe about the opengl and I've an other question :x

Where could I find how Opengl interpolate the color in a triangle ?

By example, if we got a triangle like this one :
v1(0,0,0)
v2(10,0,0)
v3(0,10,0)

with this color for each vertex,

c1(255,0,0)
c2(0,255,0)
c3(0,0,255)

How opengl calcul the color of a pixel inside this triangle (by example in 0,2,2 or any other value inside the triangle) ? 
I dont find any formula in internet...

Ty for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation of varyings over a triangle can be done in multiple ways, depended on which type of rasterizer is used.

In a [Scanline-Based rasterizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanline_rendering), one can interpolate the values first along each of the two edges that are intersected by the scanline linearly. The final color is then given by another linear interpolation between the two values from the first step.

When using a barycentric rasterizer, the interpolation of varyings is done using [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system), which is in some cases simpler to do.

This slides might also be interesting: [Link](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5600/media/Lecture%202%20-%20Barycentric%20Coordinates%20and%20Triangle%20Rasterization.pdf)